# dvips broken in texlive-2015

Tags: eps, dvips

We've recently upgraded from TeX-Live 2012 to TeX-Live 2015. Previously, dvips worked fine, and generated PS files appropriately. Since upgrading to 2015, dvips now creates PS files that have problems when EPS figures are included.

The version of dvips that was included with 2015 is -
This is dvips(k) 5.995 Copyright 2015 Radical Eye Software
kpathsea version 6.2.1
This is on Solaris 10 x86 -

```
%uname -a
SunOS xxx.cs.purdue.edu 5.10 Generic_150401-24 i86pc i386 i86pc
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Charlie

Comment: provide such an example eps file.

Comment: I think we need an indication of what sorts of EPS files cause a problem, and just exactly what those problems are. Do the EPS files not print? Do they cause PostScript errors when RIPped? If so, what errors? On what RIPs? The more information you provide, the better we can analyze this.

Comment: http://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/fultz/eps/z_chebleg.eps
http://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/fultz/eps/w_chebleg.eps
Both of those work fine with TeX-Live 2012, but fail with 2015. 
To be more specific, it seems to to be an issue with creating the DVI output. When running xdvi on the DVI file, when I get to the page with the figures, I get gs errors -
`gs: Error: /undefined in --execute--
gs: Operand stack:
gs:    11840716   9354160   1644544   328908   34272296   26312704
gs: Execution stack:
gs:    %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--`

Comment: It looks like a problem with Ghostscript. I just ran a very simple TeX file -- uses gaphicx with `\includegraphics` and both of your EPS files --  to create a DVI file and xdvi viewed it without a hiccup. Moreover, Ghostscript displayed the output from DVIPS. I am using MacTeX 2015.

Comment: But why does Ghostscript work with TeX Live 2012, but not 2015? I'm using latex to generate the DVI output. I've tried generating the DVI with TeX Live on both Solaris 10 x86 and OS X 10.9.5. Both have the same resultant problem.